# How to make file size unit to show in MB instead GB on Nemo

Tags: files, filemanager, nemo

Nemo chooses the file size unit according to his own judgement/desire, kilobytes/megabytes/gigabytes, as we can see on this screenshot below. Is there a way to limit the size unit to MB?

[image: File size unit on Nemo]